# Можно ли задать отступы и т.д. для моб устройств отдельно? (если не учитывая медиа запросы)

Tags: css, веб-программирование

Сама проблема заключается в том что верстка на bootstrap и у меня стоят для некоторых блоков отступы, а когда переходишь на моб версию из за этих отступов элементы не вмещаются, так как отступы, убираю отступы, на ПК все сжимается

Comment: медиазапросы все же должны помочь, но если никак, то есть `js` библиотеки для определения устройств. Добавьте в js в зависимости от устройства класс в `<body/>` и стройте от него стили

Comment: медиазапросы не будут мешать bootstrap'у?

Comment: Nurdaulet Adilkhan, про bootstrap не подскажу, не пользовался)

Comment: @Skywave Спасибо)